# error messages of int can't be converted to a boolean and bad operand for ||

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {



    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
        
        if ( N % 2 == 1) 
        {
        System.out.println("Weird");
        } 
        else if ( N % 2 == 0 && N <= 20 && N >= 6 )
        {
        System.out.println("Weird");
        }
        else if ( N = 2 || 4)
        {
        System.out.println("Not Weird");
        }
        else
        {
        System.out.println("Not Weird");
        }
        scanner.close();
        
        System.out.println(N);
    }
```

}

the error message Solution.java:27: error: bad operand types for binary operator '||'
else if ( N = 2 || 4)
^
first type:  int
second type: int
Solution.java:27: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean
else if ( N = 2 || 4)
^

Comment: Questions on stackoverflow should provide a [mre] and a question about the example. This question can be improved by adding a question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the following:

```
else if ( N == 2 || N == 4)
```

In this example:

```
else if ( N = 2 || 4)
```

There are 2 problems.

1. You are assigning `n` to 2, instead of comparing.
2. 4 is not a boolean

Comment: `N = 2` will not _"always return true"_, it produces an int, which cannot be converted to a boolean.